# Is "point out" appropriate in formal writing?

Tags: academic-writing, word-choice

Is it acceptable to say something like "[person] pointed out [things] as [things] that [action]" in formal academic writing?

If not, what are some phrases with similar meaning that would be appropriate?

I'm writing in American English.

Comment: It's not slang or colloquial, it's perfectly fine. Unless you're trying to write in a complicated fashion using as many long words as possible. You can find alternatives in a thesaurus.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is acceptable though if you want a potentially "more formal" sounding alternative there are: Identified, reported, highlighted, published. Each of those alternatives have different connotations so you should make sure to use the right one for the scenario.